# Extra widget showing up on form in django

Tags: python, django

I have a model Form in django. The details are as follows

forms.py

```
class QcResultForms(forms.ModelForm):
#:    series = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Series.objects.all(),help_text='Series ID adjkalsdjl',empty_label=None)
#    workflow_process = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=WorkflowsProcess.objects.all(),help_text='Workflow Process',empty_label=None)

    class Meta:
        model = QcResult
        exclude = ('id','result','workflow_process','series',)
```

models.py

```
class QcResult(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    workflows_process = models.ForeignKey('WorkflowsProcess', blank=True, null=True)
    series = models.ForeignKey('Series', blank=True, null=True)
    result = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'qc_result'
    unique_together = (('workflows_process', 'series'),)
```

views.py

```
def add_qc_results(request):
    context_dict = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QcResultForms(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/msrb/')
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = QcResultForms()
    context_dict['form'] = form
    template = get_template('msrb/add_qc_results.html')
    context = RequestContext(request,context_dict)
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context));
```

As per forms.py, it should not show anything. However,  it still shows up an extra widget like below belonging to workflow_process.

[image]

I am not sure what I am missing here

EDIT: Template

```
{% extends 'msrb/base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}
    <h1> Add QC Result </h1>
        <form id="add_qc_result"  method="post" action="/msrb/add_qc_results/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            {{ field.help_text }}
            {{ field }}
            {{ field.errors  }}
            <br/>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add QC Result" />
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

EDIT2:

On opening up inspector, I find the following code:

```html
<select id="id_workflows_process" name="workflows_process">
```

Which is same as workflow_process in QcResultForms except for empty_label=True

Comment: Can you show your template `msrb/add_qc_results.html` file?

Comment: Hi Edwin, Please find the qc_results template

Comment: right click in the browser and "inspect element" and see what the name / id of the widget is. That will help you see what is being rendered.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have mentioned that, So this is the id from inspector:

<select id="id_workflows_process" name="workflows_process">

This is same as the id that is produced by

workflow_process = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=WorkflowsProcess.objects.all(),help_text='Workflow Process',empty_label=None)

Comment: Ok. so I got some help and figured out that there was a typo which led to the extra field.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo here:

```
exclude = ('id','result','workflow_process','series',)
```

Make this:

```
exclude = ('id','result','workflows_process','series',)
```